# How do I loop through UID's in Firebase

Tags: python, arrays, json, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am using Python to go through a Firebase DB to return an array of objects, then pick one at random and return its values. I've been using a small test JSON DB that I manually build and import into Firebase. When I do this, the DB's child node's are `0, 1, 2` etc... Using the code below - I can iterate through the data and grab what I need.

I've been building a CMS that will let me input data directly into Firebase (instead of importing a local JSON doc) using the `push()` method.

Accordingly, the child nodes become obfuscated timestamps that look like this: `K036VOR90fh8sd80, KO698fhs7Hf8sfds` etc...

Now when I attempt to for-loop through the nodes, I get the following error at `ln9` `caption=....`:

`TypeError: string indices must be integers`

I'm assuming this is happening because the child nodes are strings now. Since I have to use the CMS - how do I now loop through these nodes?

Code:

```
if 'Item' in intent['slots']:
    chosen_item = intent['slots']['Item']['value']

    result = firebase.get(chosen_item, None)

    if result:
        item_object = []
        for item in result:
            item_object.append(item)

            random_item = (random.choice(item_object))
            caption = random_item['caption']
            audio_src = random_item['audioPath']
```

Here is an approximation of what the Firebase looks like:

```
 {
    "1001" : {
"-K036VOR90fh8sd80EQ" : {
  "audioPath" : "https://s3.amazonaws.com/bucket-output/audio/audio_0_1001.mp3",
  "caption" : "Record 0 from 1001"
},
"-KO698fhs7Hf8sfdsWJS" : {
  "audioPath" : "https://s3.amazonaws.com/bucket-output/audio/audio_1_1001.mp3",
  "caption" : "Record 1 from 1001"
  }
 },
 "2001" : {
  "-KOFsPBMKVtwHSOfiDJ" : {
  "audioPath" : "https://s3.amazonaws.com/bucket-output/audio/audio_0_2001.mp3",
  "caption" : "Record 0 from 2001"
},
"-KOFsQvwgF9icSIolU" : {
  "audioPath" : "https://s3.amazonaws.com/bucket-output/audio/audio_1_2001.mp3",
  "caption" : "Record 1 from 2001"
  }
 }
}
```

Comment: Can you add a link to the Python library you are using to access Firebase?

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen yes it is [python-firebase](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/python-firebase/1.2)

Answer (score 1):

What needs to be done is to strip the dictionary `result` of the parent nodes using a `for-loop` and the `.items()` Python method - through the key-values (`k,v`) and `.append` the values (`v`).

This strips the `result` of the parent Firebase dictionary keys i.e `-KOFsQvwgF9icSIolU`.

```
if 'Item' in intent['slots']:
    chosen_item = intent['slots']['Item']['value']

    result = firebase.get(chosen_item, None)

    if result:
        item_object = []
        for k,v in result.items():
            item_object.append(v)

            random_item = (random.choice(item_object))
            caption = random_item['caption']
            audio_src = random_item['audioPath']
```